# Using a proxy with Selenium does not get correct results

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I have this function that works properly, but without proxy.
It contains contents in the HTML that I need when I extract it from a [website](https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/50293998?adults=1&children=0&infants=0&check_in=2022-06-21&check_out=2022-06-28&federated_search_id=9f8562f3-653a-45b7-b6bd-218379131b41&source_impression_id=p3_1653519105_nsyk%2Fkxp2MNH1yam):

```
def extract_listing_html(url):
    
    driver_path = "C:/Users/parkj/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(driver_path))
    driver.get(url)  
    time.sleep(5)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    
    return soup
```

I want to use a proxy and this is what I have so far, but I am not getting the same results as when I am not using a proxy:

```
def extract_listing_html(url):
    
    PROXY = "164.155.145.1:80" 
    driver_path = "C:/Users/parkj/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
    chrome_options = Options()  
    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' "http://" +PROXY)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(driver_path), options = chrome_options)
    driver.get(url)  
    time.sleep(5)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    
    return soup
```

I played around with it and found out that adding `options = chrome_options` in `webdriver.Chrome( )` is what is causing it to *not* return the same HTML, but I'm not sure.

[HTML Without Proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eZsN.png)

[HTML With Proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4K6H.png)

They look quite different, not sure what is causing it.

Imports:

```
import time 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a user-agent instead has given me results.

Use `pip install pyyaml ua-parser user-agents fake-useragent` to install fake_useragent

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

def extract_listing_html(url):
    
    opts = Options()
    ua = UserAgent()
    userAgent = ua.random
    print(userAgent)
    opts.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(driver_path), options = opts)
    driver.get(url)  
    time.sleep(5)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    
    return soup
```